# knitr: how to specify different fig.paths for PNGs and SVGs

Tags: r, knitr, knitr-spin

As you will see in the minimal example below, I use `knitr::spin()` with global option `dev=c('png','svg')`. The reason is that I want the `PNG` in the report rather than the `SVG`, as I am worried that the latter will make my browser slow (my plots often have thousands of datapoints), but still want the `SVG` for preparing presentations, etc., where I want resolutions that the `PNG` can not offer *(see footnote)*.

**So my question is:** is there a way to put all PNGs into /figure/, and all SVGs into another directory (e.g. /figure/SVGs/ or /SVGs/)?

Here is the minimal example using some spin syntax, but what counts is the line with `opts_chunk`:

```
#+ RglobalOptions, include=FALSE
opts_chunk$set(width=180,dev=c('png', 'svg'))

#+ plottingCode
plot(1:5,1:5)
```

Note that I have tried `fig.path=c('figure/', 'figure/SVGs/')`, but this produces the following error:

> Error in dir.create(dirname(name), recursive = TRUE) :
> invalid 'path' argument

Looking forward to your answers!

Felix

---

*footnote: while I could set fig.width/height to 14 or so, this makes dots, font size etc. awkwardly small; and while there are options to change this awkwardly, outputting an SVG as well is elegant and effective*